# Refining My Eloquent Query (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Edited for Clarity:

I need some way for this Query to only return distinct course_ids in the

```
->wherein('course_id', $array)
```

part of the query. It gets the total number of completed courses, but if a user has completed a course more than once it counts it toward the total. So if you want to know how many students have done a course, the number will be off if a student has completed a course more than once.

```
    public function report_count(){
    $array = \Session::get('course_report')['course'];
    return $this->hasOne('Tracking', 'roster_id')
        ->selectRaw('roster_id, count(*) as aggregate')
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->wherein('course_id', $array)
        ->groupBy('roster_id');
```

I've tried adding groupBy('course_id') at the end but it does not work.

Comment: Could this statistics be generated in a cronjob?

Comment: Is this a memory issue? A timeout issue? You could chunk the queries, or pre-process them via cron. Are you using debugbar to see what your query is like?

Comment: A memory issue at first. I upped the memory and now I believe it times out. We have a lot of cronjobs already, but I could check with the senior dev to see if he has any ideas about pre-running these. I have been using debugbar, the query for the roster is fine, then it spits out n+1 queries for each of these relations. I tried to eager load the query, but it just changes the value to 0 for each of the completed courses.

Comment: This may or may not help, but have you run similar queries on the database ? Are you sure that the database is properly indexed? Are there opportunities to index the db further to help your cause? Have you used the mysql EXPLAIN clause to see what indexes the queries are using for example? If there are db issues, it is unlikely query tweaks will help. Finally can u share the db structure?

Comment: Yes, the database is working great, even for huge queries. See my edit toward the bottom of the question using jarek tkaczyk's eager loading technique. I can get that to run against all of the matches in less than half a second, the only problem is that it doesn't give me the total correctly. I just need to know what kind of subquery to run in the wherein() to get the correct completed course count.

Comment: can u show an example value for $array

Comment: Why dont you try the `DISTINCT column` in SQL?

Comment: add `->distinct()`

Comment: @tam $array is equal to a session variable that is stored based on the drop down selection.

Comment: @Robin R I'm not very good with SQL, I would have to look up the syntax for something akin to ->whereraw('get courses from this list of courses, but only get one of each course and not two or more from a single completed course'). If you have an idea for how to accomplish this, you may have answered my question.

Comment: @kkyeboah Nope, does not work. Nor does ->groupBy(course_id). Tried them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Changed the query to

```
return $this->hasOne('Tracking', 'roster_id')
        ->selectRaw('roster_id, count(distinct course_id) as aggregate')
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->wherein('course_id', $array)
        ->groupBy('roster_id');
```

per @Robin R suggestion, I went on a search of ways to utilize SQL in my selectRaw query instead of trying this the eloquent way. Thanks to all who helped me brainstorm though this one.

Comment: Good to hear it helped! mark your own answer as solved.